# Liferay.PortletURL is undefined

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-aui

Want to implement:
I have two pages with one portlet each. On click of link i want to move from first page portlet to another page portlet.
For that i have written:

```
<aui:script>
 function openCompanyPage(companyId) {   
     AUI().use(
             'liferay-portlet-url',
             'aui-resize-iframe',
             function(A) {
                 var navigationURL;
```

> **var portletURL = Liferay.PortletURL.createRenderURL();**

```
                 var url = themeDisplay.getLayoutURL();               
                portletURL.setParameter("employerId", companyId);
                portletURL.setPortletId(A.one('#custSupportPortletId'));
                navigationURL = portletURL.toString();
                window.location = navigationURL;
            }
    );

</aui:script>
```

but i am getting error as Liferay.PortletURL is undefined on bold line.
I have already provided :

```
    <%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/ui" prefix="liferay-ui" %>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/aui" prefix="aui" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/portlet" prefix="liferay-portlet"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/util" prefix="liferay-util"%>
```

Please let me know the possible reason for this.

OR 
What is other way to create the Render portlet URL.

Comment: can you please verify if you are missing $theme.include($top_head_include)  in your theme

Comment: Can you check if there is any other javascript error in the page?

Comment: Only one error: TypeError: a is null .. i think this error is related to firebox only

Comment: that error is preventing the other modules to be loaded, I think.

Comment: That problem comes for firefox only ..not other browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**
I resolved the issue by brute force.

**Before:**
`<a href="" onclick="openCDPPage('${individual.individualId}')">${individual.individualName}`
**After :**

```
<a onclick="openCDPPage('${individual.individualId}')">${individual.individualName}</a>
```

**Changes in the script:**

```
<script>
     function openCompanyPage(companyId) {   
         AUI().use(**'liferay-portlet-url'**,
                 function(A) {
                     var navigationURL;
        var portletURL = Liferay.PortletURL.createRenderURL();
                     var url = themeDisplay.getLayoutURL();               
                    portletURL.setParameter("employerId", companyId);
                    portletURL.setPortletId(A.one('#custSupportPortletId'));
                    navigationURL = portletURL.toString();
                    window.location = navigationURL;
                }
        );

    </script>
```

This solved my issue.
I am not sure whether this is the perfect solution for the problem or not.
Expert please let us know.